# corssbar.io (WAMP socket server) cant keep up with

Tags: rabbitmq, wamp, router

Here is the set up

1. RabbitMQ -> were notification messages are queued.
2. Wamp router -> which is pub sub, a consumer of queue and sends socket messages to subscribers.

Wamp router cant keep up with the number of messages that are coming into the queue. what should i do ?  if you have more questions i would be happy to answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am using Crossbar.io and autobahn.

Comment: Load balance the wamp router.

Comment: What router implementation are you using?

Comment: Is the **router** not able to handle the load or are the back-end processes (the subscribers) not capable of handling the load?

Comment: @Meg you need to clarify your question. Do you mean that you are using crossbar.io to pull messages from RabbitMQ? What are you using to do that? Your setup is somewhat funny, since RabbitMQ and crossbar.io are both routers...